# How to use IndexSet to find item in a custom Struct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, nsindexset

I'm trying to use SwiftUI's `.delete` method on a list to identify what `HKWorkout` the user is trying to delete, but since I package my workouts into a custom WorkoutMonth object, I'm having difficulty figuring out how I can dig down into the specific workout the user is tapping on?  In UIKIT i was able to use `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` to find it, but here I am lost.

```
struct MonthsWorkoutsListView: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject var trackerDataStore: TrackerDataStore
    @State var workouts: [TrackerWorkout]
    @State var workoutMonths = [WorkoutMonth]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if workoutMonths.count == 0 {
                Text("No workouts logged yet.  Open the Athlytic App on your Apple Watch to start and save a new workout.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(workoutMonths) { workoutMonth in
                        Section(header: Text(getFormattedYearMonth(workoutMonth: workoutMonth))) {
                            ForEach(workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts) { workout in
                                NavigationButton(
                                    action: {
                                        trackerDataStore.selectedWorkout = workout //this line is needed so that the image  at the top of WorkoutDetailHeaderCard gets updated,  otherwise the view loads before the async called and you end up with the  image of the last selected workout
                                        trackerDataStore.loadDataForSelectedWorkout(selectedWorkoutToBeUpdated: workout)
                                    },
                                    destination: {
                                        WorkoutDetailView().environmentObject(trackerDataStore)
                                    },
                                    workoutRow: { WorkoutRow(trackerWorkout: workout) }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Workouts"))
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            workoutMonths = buildWorkoutsIntoYearMonths(workouts: workouts)
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {

        //How to look up the workout user wants to delete?

    }

struct YearMonth: Comparable, Hashable {
    
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    
    init(year: Int, month: Int) {
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
    }
    
    init(date: Date) {
        let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: date)
        self.year = comps.year!
        self.month = comps.month!
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: YearMonth, rhs: YearMonth) -> Bool {
        if lhs.year != rhs.year {
            return lhs.year < rhs.year
        } else {
            return lhs.month < rhs.month
        }
    }
}

struct WorkoutMonth: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var yearMonth: YearMonth
    var trackerWorkouts: [TrackerWorkout]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had my `.delete` under the outside `forEach` and placing it here gave me access to the `workoutMonth`

```
ForEach(workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts) { workout in
    NavigationButton(
        action: {
            trackerDataStore.selectedWorkout = workout
            trackerDataStore.loadDataForSelectedWorkout(selectedWorkoutToBeUpdated: workout)
        },
        destination: {
            WorkoutDetailView().environmentObject(trackerDataStore)
        },
        workoutRow: { WorkoutRow(trackerWorkout: workout) }
    )
}
.onDelete { (offSets) in
    for offset in offSets {
    print("user wants to delete workout \(workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts[offset].startDate)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have `IndexSet` passed as parameter. This one can be used to remove proper workouts

```
workoutMonths.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
```

If you want to gather all objects that should be deleted, you can iterate using foreach loop as well. Then you get access to each of objects that will be removed.

```
for offset in offsets {
   var workoutMonth: WorkoutMonth = workoutMonths[offset]
}
```

Comment: I can't just use `.remove(atOffsets)` because I need to call .delete on the workout in Apple's HealthKit API.  And I can't use the 2nd example because i don't know how many offsets there are.

Comment: @GarySabo why do you need to know exact count ? isn't just for-each enough ? You have count available as well on it. I don't quite get the problem.
If you need exact workout objects - best will be to use for each loop, create an array of those removed objects and then remove them from HealthKit API as a collection of objects

Comment: I need access to the workout.  The problem is I have access to the workout in the `ForEach(workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts) { workout in` correct, but my .delete is outside of that loop so I don't have it to pass into `HKHealthStore.delete(workout)`